# Git - Stop file from being merged into another branch

Tags: git, git-merge

I have build files created for each branch/environment, but I don't want to override the build scripts when I merge from one branch to the other. Is it possible to do this?

I want to still make changes to the build file and push up to the branches origin, but I don't want that file to override another environments build file when I merge one branch into another.

Ben

Answer (score 0):

If the build files are tracked by in the same repository, there's no easy way to do this. You could move the build files in their own repo that track the environment rather than track the code-in-main.

It may be too much abstraction in your case, but in theory you'd want to put the build logic dependent on the code base in the repo with the code base and the build logic/variables dependent on the environment in a repo associated with the environment.